# Getting list of all databases with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are some similar questions but all of them involves using the [MongoDB NodeJS driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/) instead of [Mongoose ODM](http://mongoosejs.com/).

I read [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) but couldn't find such functionality.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't directly get the list from the connection provided by mongoose, but it's easy to do with the mongo `Admin` object as it contains a function called `listDatabases`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

/// create a connection to the DB    
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(
    'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
connection.on('open', function() {
    // connection established
    new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
        console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
        // database list stored in result.databases
        var allDatabases = result.databases;    
    });
});
```

Comment: Where does "Admin" come from? Appreciate this is an old answer but the closest I've found yet to an answer. I'm getting an error: "Cannot find name Admin".

Comment: Just declare the variable Admin. ```var Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin```

Answer (score 2):

A very modern approach to get list of all mongo databases using mongoose  (version 6.10.*) is to ***Create a mongoose connection to connect to Mongo's admin database*** and make sure you have an **admin user**.

Mongoose object is a very complex object. To list the db's :

```js
const connection = `mongodb://${encodeURIComponent(username)}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@${hostname}:${port}/admin`
```

mongoose is a very complex object with promises for executing several functions. to list the db's :

```js
mongoose.connect(connection,  {  useNewUrlParser: true ,  useUnifiedTopology: true }).then( (MongooseNode) => { 

/* I use the default nativeConnection object since my connection object uses a single hostname and port. Iterate here if you work with multiple hostnames in the connection object */
                    
const nativeConnetion =  MongooseNode.connections[0]

//now call the list databases function
    new Admin(nativeConnetion.db).listDatabases(function(err, results){
        console.log(results)  //store results and use
    });
})
```

Result:

```
{ databases:
   [ { name: 'admin', sizeOnDisk: 184320, empty: false },
     { name: 'config', sizeOnDisk: 73728, empty: false },
     { name: 'local', sizeOnDisk: 73728, empty: false },
     { name: 'test', sizeOnDisk: 405504, empty: false } ],
  totalSize: 737280,
  ok: 1 }
```

Comment: from where you imported `Admin`?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work. It says 'Admin' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for answers from the latest version of Mongoose and Mongodb, the below code can be used.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;

// Check DB Connection
db.once('open', () => {
  (async () => {
    const data = await mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({
      listDatabases: 1,
    });
    console.log(data);
  })();
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

// Check for DB errors
db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('DB Connection errors', err);
});

export default mongoose;
```

If you want to get the database list on your other functions, make sure the connection is established first and also make sure the user has admin access and then just do the below query. This is a sample from my API router.

```
// Get all databases

router.get('/database/get', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({
      listDatabases: 1,
    });
    if (data && data !== null) {
      res.status(200).send({ data: data });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send({ data: null, message: 'Data not found' });
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send(e.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -6):

Try running [this code](http://runnable.com/URl7hlgo6eZ2AAJc/mongoose?f=code.js). Original take from [Gist](https://gist.github.com/edwardhotchkiss/2785463).

Comment: I think he's looking for the names of the available databases, not the collections.