# How to check if a database exists with mongoose.createConnection()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I want to create multiple connections using mongoose. Therefore, I've chosen to use `mongoose.createConnection()` instead of `mongoose.connect()`.

When I connect on my localhost, I want to check if the database that I'm connecting to exists.

My connection to a non-existing database:
`let db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/nonexistentdb');`

Nevertheless, the events still give the the following results:

```
db.on('open', function() {
    console.log("Opened"); // <= logged
});

db.on('connected', function () {  
    console.log('Connected'); // <= logged 
});

db.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Unable to connect to database"); // <= not logged
});
```

*Note: It does log the error event on a non-existing database when using `mongoose.connect()`.*

**How do I check for database existence using `mongoose.createConnection()`?**

Comment: Any help from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997020/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-mongo-from-the-node-js-driver ?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822550/getting-list-of-all-databases-with-mongoose

Comment: Also, why would you need to know if it is non-existant? Are you getting databases dynamically? If not, then I would just connect to databases that are valid

Comment: @chapinkapa I'm trying to use multi-tenant databases (one database per customer), as explained [here](https://docs.compose.io/use-cases/multi-tenant.html). These are based on a subdomain like ``customer1.site.com``, so I want to check if the corresponding  database (aka subdomain) exists.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. That's is going to get confusing with how many connections you are going to have to throw up. Did that other stackoverflow help though?

Comment: @chapinkapa I see it uses a method which connects as an admin, which I definitely want to avoid. I'm considering storing all customers in the default database (which I will always connect to), and check for existence there. Thoughts?

Comment: I think that is good. I am guessing that you are just getting started with this project. An architecture like this is pretty advance for just getting started. I would go with the proven way of putting them all in the same database.

Comment: I'm already at a fairly advanced level of Node.js and MongoDB (using mongoose), but this is the first time using this architecture, so I decided to look for more opinions on my decisions. Thank you for your responses really!