# Why does this MongoDB aggregate query return nothing?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregate query:

```
db.radars.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$locationId',
            count: {$sum: 1}
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            loggedAt: {
                $gte: new Date('2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                $lte: new Date('2016-12-31T00:00:00Z')
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

I definitely have data matching the criteria:

[image]

But I get nothing:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: try to match the datefields with timestamp instead of dateStrings,       `loggedAt: {
                $gte: new Date(1388534400),
                $lte: new Date(1483142400)
            }`

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. Using `loggedAt: {$push: '$loggedAt'}` helps, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the `$group`, the pipeline will contain docs with just the fields defined in the `$group`: `_id` and `count` so there's no `loggedAt` field to match against.

So, depending on the output you're looking for, reorder your pipeline to do the `$match` first or add an accumulator for `loggedAt` to your `$group` so its still available.

For example:

```
db.radars.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$locationId',
            count: {$sum: 1},
            loggedAt: {$push: '$loggedAt'}
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            loggedAt: { $elemMatch: {
                $gte: new Date('2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                $lte: new Date('2016-12-31T00:00:00Z')
            } }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Interesting. This works. Strangely I swear I had it working previously with the query I posted. The query seems to still work if I remove `$elemMatch` -- is `$elemMatch` necessary?

Comment: The `$elemMatch` ensures that the match is made against a single `loggedAt` element that satisfies _both_ the >= and <= terms, rather than one element matching the >= part and another the <= part.

Comment: I see. Interesting. I'm noticing now that the value for `loggedAt` of every single document found per locationId is now included in the aggregate result. I have millions of documents, and so the result exceeds 16MB. Is there a way to avoid including `loggedAt`?

Comment: Ah wait...reordering as you suggested solves it. Thanks again!

Comment: Or just add a `{$project: {_id: 1, count: 1}}` stage at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If some of your aggregation queries return a result, but some return no result, then you need to fix your query (other answers address this).

But if none of your aggregation queries return a result, you may not be connected to the right database.

**Connect to a database using a connection string**

Check your connection string. Note `databasename` in the following:

`MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.abcdefg.mongodb.net/databasename`

**Connect to a database using Mongoose connection options object**

[How to connect to a specific database ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337218/how-to-connect-to-specific-database-with-mongoose-and-node)

**Connect to a database using MongoDB shell**

`show dbs;` to list the databases

`use mydatabase;` to connect to a database

If you aren't sure which one you should be using, after connecting to a database you can run

`show collections` in MongoDB shell to see if it contains your data.

**Listing databases and collections using NodeJS:**

[List databases with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822550/getting-list-of-all-databases-with-mongoose))

[List collections with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470415/listing-all-collections-in-a-mongo-database-within-a-nodejs-script)