# How to connect to specific database with Mongoose and node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning how to use Mongoose and there's something I don't understand - how can I connect to specific database and collection in my cluster?

I have 5 different databases and each database have few different collections

When I was using pure Mongo client - the way the show it in official documentation, I connected like that:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = process.env.mongo_connection_string;

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("database_name").collection("collection_name");

       // Do some work here in the selected database and the selected collection
  client.close();
});
```

Now I want to use Mongoose to practice. So in my app.js to establish the connection I do:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.mongo_connection_string , {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then( () => console.log("Connection established"))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Then I have created a schema for one of the objects I want to store in the database.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
module.exports = User
```

How do I associate this model with the database and the collection I need?

Answer (score 7):

To connect to a specific database you can add the name in the options like this:

```
mongoose
  .connect(db_url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'MyDatabaseName',
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to the Database.');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: In my case, MongoDB Atlas created a DB named test and I couldn't figure out how to save data to the DB I created. Although this answer corrected my issue, MongoDB continued creating DB with the name test when I enter data.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the database name in URI like [link](https://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html) (or) 
Please get the default client object with mongo URI then get the required database and collection objects.